# How do I change MATLAB preferences from code, not from menu?

Tags: matlab

I have a MATLAB preference that I have figured out how to check from the preferences menu (General > MAT-Files > MAT-file save format), but want to change it programmatically so that I can distribute the change in the startup.m file.  I can't find it.

Does someone know how to do this and/or have a suggestion of where to look?

Thanks.

Comment: Specify which options do you want to modify programmatically. Some of them are, some others aren't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this I believe you would need to edit the `matlab.prf` file, which can be done programatically...

The line we want to change is

```
MatfileSaveFormat=xxxxx
```

where `xxxxx` can either be `Sv6`, `Sv7` or `Sv7.3` relating to -v6, -v7 and -v7.3 respectively.

so to find the line we want to change, load file into a cell array, find the location of the element containing the text `'MatfileSaveFormat='` and replace that element with `'MatfileSaveFormat=Sv7.3'` (or the suitable line for the required version), finally overwrite the file with the updated version.

```
pref = regexp( fileread(fullfile(prefdir,'matlab.prf')), '\n', 'split');
pref{find(~cellfun(@isempty,regexp(pref,'MatfileSaveFormat=')))}=...
    'MatfileSaveFormat=Sv7.3';

fid = fopen(fullfile(prefdir,'matlab.prf'), 'w');
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', A{:});
fclose(fid);
```

note: in 2013a this does not update the settings when viewed, but does effect the file type coming out of `save()`

The Following is modified to account for line not yet existing in `matlab.prf` , which it appears is the case if the preference has never been changed.

```
pref = regexp( fileread(fullfile(prefdir,'matlab.prf')), '\n', 'split');
loc = find(~cellfun(@isempty,regexp(pref,'MatfileSaveFormat=')));

if isempty(loc); pref{end+1} = 'MatfileSaveFormat=Sv7.3';
else;            pref{loc} = 'MatfileSaveFormat=Sv7.3';
end

fid = fopen(fullfile(prefdir,'matlab.prf'), 'w');
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', A{:});
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I found `matlab.prf` but couldn't find `MatfileSaveFormat`.  I'm running Matlab on _Linux_ and on _Windows_.  It looks like the _Linux_ version of `matlab.prf` includes the field but the _Windows_ version does not.  Adding `MatfileSaveFormat` to the _Windows_ `matlab.prf` file works, as does modifying it as @RTL suggests.

Comment: Just checked another machine, it appears it is not part of the .prf added until the format has been changed in settings

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/changing-system-preferences-programmatically) for a solution. Basically Yair shows how to modify preferences by accessing the "matlab.prf" text file as follow:

```
edit(fullfile(prefdir,'matlab.prf'));
```

Hope that helps!