# How to change the MATLAB command window scroll buffer programmatically?

Tags: matlab

Each new session of MATLAB that I startup has the command window scroll buffer default to 5,000 lines. I'd like there to be something which I can put in my *startup.m* in order to change this to the maximum of 25,000, without having to do this by hand. Does anyone know a way?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you do it by hand?

Comment: It believe it should remember the changes made through the preferences UI (under enviroment), however I could be wrong... if so see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25327784/how-do-i-change-matlab-preferences-from-code-not-from-menu) the preference you want to change is `CommandWindowMinSessionSize` and the line will look something like `CommandWindowMinSessionSize=I25000` (note the `I`)

Comment: Remember your command window buffer resides **in memory**. This may not be an issue but if it is, a work around would be to use the command [`diary`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diary.html) in your `startup.m` (without forgetting to also close the diary in `finish.m`). This way you're not even limited to 25000 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I change the scroll buffer of my Matlab installations (2010, 2013a), my changes are kept after restarting Matlab. Which version are you using?

To change the preferences programmatically/manually, you would have to edit the preferences file(s). `prefdir` is going to give you the directory of the preferences files. There is an entry `CommandWindowMinSessionSize` in the `matlab.prf` file, if you change it, you should get what you want.

Comment: I agree on the changes being kept... just a warning to future readers, the entry is only added to `matlab.prf` after it has been modified